# How to order non-integer records in MySql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to order some MySQL records by DESC order and get the last record added.

These are my records and they're all stored as strings:

```
1/2017
1/2018
2/2017
2/2018
3/2017
```

I want to get the value 1/2018.   The records are based on the current year
and the last record added was 1/2018 and the next will be 2/2018 and so on.

this is my query:

```
SELECT NoControl FROM cita ORDER BY NoControl DESC LIMIT 1
```

but I'm getting 3/2017 as the last record.

Comment: Are those `datetime` fields?

Comment: Don't store dates as strings, use the native database date/time types. That said, if you have to store dates as strings, use a "most significant value first" format like YYYY/MM/DD and then they will naturally sort correctly.

Comment: Bit of a tip for you: It pays off to think before doing anything and what you did here isn't good practice. Storing dates other than using the already built-in MySQL functions for dates (and times) always work best. If you're not too far into this, it's probably not too late to redesign your database.

Comment: If only it was the other way round eh?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ever the same pattern  m/yyyy you could use some string manipulation function  eg:

```
SELECT NoControl 
FROM cita 
ORDER BY right(NoControl,4), DESC left(NoControl,1) DESC  LIMIT 1
```

But you should avoid of store date values as string ..

or convert the string as  a proper date

```
SELECT NoControl 
FROM cita 
ORDER BY str_to_date(NoControl,'%m/%Y') DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract the first and second part, CAST as integer and sort:

```
SELECT str
FROM testdata
ORDER BY 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, '/', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, '/',  1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8be8b8/3)